# Is there a way to add a function that will get run after a blog is created?

Tags: multisite, customization

Is there a way to have a function run after a blog is created in WP MU? I think I would need to add a filter or something but I'm not as familiar with the procedure.

Do I set something up like this:

```
EXAMPLE!!!
add_filter('new_blog_created', 'my_function');


function my_function() {
    // do something
}
```

So far I'm calling `wpmu_create_blog()` to create a new blog successfully if that helps.

Here is my code which is inside a function:

```
function create_site() {
    // some code
    $meta = apply_filters( 'add_signup_meta', $meta );

    $result = wpmu_create_blog( $domain, $path, $blog_title, $current_user->ID, $meta, $wpdb->siteid );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the action 'wpmu_new_blog' .

The docstring for the function 'wpmu_create_blog' says:

- This function runs when a user self-registers a new site as well
- as when a Super Admin creates a new site. Hook to 'wpmu_new_blog'
- for events that should affect all new sites.

wpmu_new_blog is called with the following parameters:

```
do_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', $blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta );
```

Comment: Would I make a filter for "wpmu_new_blog" then?

Comment: You can simply add an action , for example your function my_function() will be run after the blog is created .add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'my_function' );

Comment: Is the "." before "add_action" important? Where do I place this code? BTW I updated my example code. What I mean is do I place it inside of a function before I call "wpmu_new_blog" or outside of the function?